# Database compatibility level

Tags: sql-server-2008, compatibility-level

We are on SQL Server 2008 R2 and have DBs compatibility level set to SQL 2000 or 2005.

What are differences in compatibility level across the versions ?

Are there any advantages changing it to 2008 or higher?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of differences.  One that comes to mind right away is the MERGE statement, which first became available in 2008.

Comment: MERGE works fine regardless of compatibility level, though.

Comment: Good point.  I was thinking of version rather than compatibility level.